# How to ask the reason of the call

Tags: phrase-choice

When I get a call, sometimes I can't get what is the reason of the call.
Even if he explained it at first place.

How can I ask about that?

"Can you say it again what is this call about?" 
Is this good expression in case like this?

Comment: "Sorry, I don't quite understand what you mean. Could you please explain again what you are calling about?"

Comment: @PaulPehrson gave a good answer.  To hew very close to your original suggestion:  _"Can you say it again what is this call about?"_ isn't quite grammatical.  In this case, the _it_ is not necessary, and the _is_ should be moved: _"Can you say again what this call is about?"_  would be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also say something like: *"I'm sorry, I am having a hard time understanding you. Can you tell me again what this call is about?"*

Be clear and direct. If it is a language issue, it is okay to explain that openly. Something like, *"I'm still learning English, and I don't understand what you are calling about."* Or if the language deficiency is on the part of the caller, *"I'm sorry. I'm having a difficult time understanding you because of your accent. Can you please restate the purpose of the call?"*

Comment: +1, although I don't know if I would say "...because of your accent."  If their accent is that bad, they probably know it, and _" I'm having a difficult time understanding you. Can you please restate the purpose of the call?"_ gets the point across without calling out their English skills.

Comment: Good point. I think your idea is best, especially the first time you ask to restate. If you STILL need the person to restate, I think stating the reason you need them to restate is helpful. If it is because of the accent, then maybe the person needs to speak more clearly. If I'm having a hard time understanding because I don't understand the technical jargon you are using, then stating that is helpful. I sometimes tend to favor over communication so the person knows why you are having trouble.